# How to include multiple URI's for same property in Jena Model?

Tags: rdf, jena

Hi is there a more efficient way to create the following:

```
.addProperty(RDF.type, locah+"/Repository")
.addProperty(RDF.type, DCTerms.Agent)
.addProperty(RDF.type, FOAF.Agent);
```

What are the advantages of having a resource with multiple RDF.types?

Comment: There are no "advantages" - either it makes sense to have multiple types or not. It's just a matter of "completeness".

Comment: More efficient via Jena API? Efficiency in terms of what? Regarding conciseness: not really besides Java streams/loops. Alternative way would be SPARQL Update.

Comment: By using different rdf:type relations you may classify your instance against different taxonomies, it matters when you model particular domain which require such technique. Can't comment about the 'efficiency'.,.,

Answer (score 1):

## Multiple RDF types

In computational ontologies, an instance can have multiple *classes* (types).

**Classification**

This can be confusing at first, because for example in medical *classification* this is different. There you have to choose exactly one "class" for an instance. So a doctor has to pick exactly one ICD 10 code for the primary diagnosis.

You can imagine such classification schemes like a cutlery drawer in a kitchen where you have to decide whether something is a spoon, fork or knive and then put it in the appropriate compartment. There is no "spoonfork" that you can place in two compartments at the same time.

However there are problems when the rare exception occurs where something really does not fit anywhere. To account for this, you need "left over" classes, where you can put those exceptions.

**Ontologies**

Now the semantics of ontologies are different: A *class* is just a set of its members (whether those members are specified explicitly or not). This means, a resource having multiple classes (types) just means it belongs to multiple sets.

**Examples**

- the number 2 belongs to the set of prime numbers, the set of even numbers, the set of whole numbers *and* the set of positive numbers
- John Doe *is a* man, *a* husband and *a* father. ("is a" means "belongs to the set of")

## Efficient Way to Create Multiple Type Statements

Jena 3.12.0 does not contain a method to add multiple properties more concisely. However, as @AKSW suggested, if you have a large number of statements (3 would probably not be worth it), you can use a loop, such as:

`types.forEach(type->{resource.addProperty(RDF.type, type);});`

**Working Example**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.OWL;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDF;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.SKOS;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        Resource resource = model.createResource("test");
        List<Resource> types = List.of(OWL.Class, RDFS.Class,SKOS.Concept);

        types.forEach(type->{resource.addProperty(RDF.type, type);});       
    }

}
```