# Multiple properties to define same concept

Tags: rdf, jena, rdfs

In RDF example sometimes I am finding different properties to define the same concept ex:

```
.addProperty(FOAF.name, "Archives, "en")
.addProperty(RDFS.label, "Archives", "en")
```

What is the reason that this is done?

Comment: Simply because people may use different way to define a same concept. As synonyms work.

Comment: Thankyou...therefore it is better to offer synonyms I guess in the model right?

Comment: Why did you create the same question twice?

Comment: @AKSW: Do you mean [How to include multiple URI's for same property in Jena Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52623064/1591669)? I would they aren’t the same. --- Anyway, in my opinion, it would make sense to make the other question about Jena (and to remove the side question about advantages) and this one about RDF and remove the Jena reference.